# Internet explorer 10 wrong behavior with HTML5 video is it other browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, html5-video, internet-explorer-10

With [this test](http://w3c-test.org/html/tests/submission/Google/video/paused/paused_true_during_pause.html), IE10 dev-preview shows very strange behavior. It passes the test but continue the playback while it should remain at the paused state. Other browsers don't show this behavior.

Given the following piece of code (extracted from the embedded script in ), should the video start playing after passing the test?

```
var t = async_test("video.paused should be true during pause event", {timeout:30000});
var v = document.getElementById("v");
v.addEventListener("pause", function() {
   t.step(function() {
      assert_true(v.paused);
   });
   t.done();
}, false);
v.src = getVideoURI("http://media.w3.org/2010/05/video/movie_300") + "?" + new Date() + Math.random();
v.play();
v.pause();
```

Comment: btw if you are a connect subscriber, this issue is already submitted on [connect website](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/689637/html5-video-doesnt-persist-the-paused-state) as is.